# Find int in nxn matrix while each quarter is sorted clockwise (circular array) - With complexity limit

Tags: java, matrix, time-complexity, space-complexity

I try to find given number in nXn matrix (when n is a power of 2).
In addition each quareter of the mat is sorted in the shown way.
[image: clockwise]

I also need to refer the time and space complexity.

At first I used two nested loops but this gives complexity time n ^ 2. In addition it does not take advantage of the special sorting of the matrix.

```html
for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
    for(int j=0; j<n;j++)
      {
       // chechk each cell
      }
    }
```

Than I thought to sort each row of the mat using one of known sorting algorithms, but if I do it in for loop (or while) it is not really reduce the comlexity.

Another way is to jump every n/2 cells so we check only the greater cell in each quarter, but have doubts that this way is correct.

I would like to hear if one of my suggestions are correct or if I missed something important while try to find solution.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand the question correctly, you should be able to binary search the location of the number in the matrix. You can imagine if you stretched the matrix out into one long array based on this somewhat strange matrix traversal, the array you got would be sorted. Finding a number in a sorted array is `O(log(x))` where x is the array length, and since the number of elements in this long array from the `n*n` matrix would be `n^2`, the complexity of this binary search would be `O(log(n^2)) = O(2log(n)) = O(log(n))`. So, `O(log(n))` is what we're targeting here for our runtime.

Now, since each quarter of the matrix is sorted as shown, we know that for any given quarter, the lowest element in that quarter of the matrix is the top-left. So we can determine where the target number x is by first checking quarter 3's top-left element, and then checking 4's or 2's to narrow in what quarter of the matrix the target value is in, similar to a binary search. Thus, determining which quarter of the matrix the target value lies requires 2 checks and reduces the search space by 1/4. We can recurse on the resulting quarter of the array, repeatedly narrowing on which sixteenth, sixty-fourth, etc. of the array until we are down to a 2x2 subsection of the matrix, in which base case we can just check all four and then we're done!

In each step of the algorithm just described, we do 2 comparisons, and reduce the search space by 1/4. This is equivalent to doing 1 comparison and reducing the seach space by 1/2, twice, which is simply a binary search. Thus, the runtime of this algorithm is `O(log(n^2)) = O(2log(n)) = O(log(n))`

Best of luck implementing this!

Comment: thanks，binary search actually has the optimal complexity. I  will try this.

Comment: if this works, please accept my answer! Thanks :)